# UDP hole punching is working with google colab but not other local nats

Tags: c, networking, p2p, nat

I'm making an p2p application with c. I made basic program which communicates peer by udp hole punching. Now my program works fine when I run a program from my PC an another from google colab.
But when tried it with my friend's pc which under another ISP (different ISP from mine) it doesn't work. Again if my friend tries it with google colab it works fine.

I tried stun test in my pc, colab, and my friends results are like these:

**Mine:**

```
test I = 1
test II = 0
test III = 0
test I(2) = 1
is nat  = 1
mapped IP same = 1
hairpin = 0
preserver port = 1
Primary: Independent Mapping, Port Dependent Filter, preserves ports, no hairpin
Return value is 0x000017
```

**colab:**

```
test I = 1
test II = 0
test III = 0
test I(2) = 1
is nat  = 1
mapped IP same = 1
hairpin = 1
preserver port = 1
Primary: Independent Mapping, Port Dependent Filter, preserves ports, will hairpin  
Return value is 0x000007
```

**my friend's:**

```
test I = 1
test II = 0
test III = 0
test I(2) = 1
is nat  = 1
mapped IP same = 1
hairpin = 0
preserver port = 1
Primary: Independent Mapping, Port Dependent Filter, preserves ports, no hairpin
Return value is 0x000017
```

**I used ttl 255 where pinging with my fiends nat shows required ttl of 62. Is it the cause?Ping command shows ttl 112 for google colab. I'm currently trying this program from Bangladesh.**

Comment: Pinging is ICMP protocol that is often blocked to prevent DNS attacks https://superuser.com/questions/912875/how-ping-a-server-which-has-icmp-blocked

Comment: Hmm..But it worked on my friends nat. Ping is not blocking by nat.

Comment: Can your friend ping your machine your local network ? You have to ping the external address of your friends NAT not his specific machines address that is internal

Comment: Yes, I pinged my friends public address. And my friend can do the same.

Comment: Very likely the firewall settings, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol#Data

Comment: Does udp hole punching requires ICMP messages ???

Comment: No ICMP is on a lower layer than UDP and UDP does not use ICMP

Comment: You said a "Firewall setting". How to fix?